# How do I make text appear when a div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to make a div display text when I clicked on it

I have this code and it supposed to make the image inside the "songPlay" div display "demo" text when I clicked it but it doesnt. I dont know anything about js so please help me. Thankyou

This is the code:

`<script>`

`var tag = document.getElementById('demo');`

`var button = document.querySelector('songPlay');`

`button.addEventListener('click', function(){`

`tag.classList.toggle('demo');`

`});`

`</script>`

`<p id='demo'>Audio is playing</p>`

`<div id="flex-container">`

`<div id="flex-container2">`

`<div id="songPlay" onclick="play('song'); toggleText();">`

`<div class="play1">`

`<img src="images/play.png" width="15px" height="15px">`

`</div>`

`</div>`

Comment: One, it looks like you are trying to access the elements before they exist - for details, see duplicate. Two, `querySelector` works with CSS selectors. `querySelector('songPlay')` would look for an element with the _tag name_ `songPlay`; you need to prefix that with a `.` if you want to select the first element of a class, or with a `#` if you want to select an element with that ID.